# Git rebase --interactive blocks on index.lock

Tags: git, git-rebase

Using git 1.7.10 on linux I am trying to use git rebase -i on a branch of about 100 commits. I regularly but not always run into this problem:

After I have indicated which changes I want to make... eg. I just do a reword quite near the upstream part, git keeps running and shows a counter in the command line while applying the commits: like [17/100]...

This should normally be a quite smooth operation but often it stops in the middle somewhere saying:

> [detached HEAD 5e1a3c8]  Commit message
>   Author: username
>   1 file changed, 14 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
>   fatal: Unable to create '/[path to repository]/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> Could not apply 05e6b8ef Other commit message

When I run git rebase --continue I get shown the commit message of the current commit and when I close the file git rebase continues but it omits that commit... That is quite useless so for the moment I just do --abort, but it is a pain...

Maybe it will be possible to manually commit the problematic commit and then --continue, but I haven't looked into that yet.

In any case when I go and check index.lock does not exist. Maybe it existed at the moment when git wanted to create it, but it definitely got removed before I can look at it with a file browser...

**ps**: I can't seem to reproduce this if I don't have gitg open while rebasing.

Any clues?

**update**: updating to gitg 2.6 seems to have solved the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That file is created to make sure two clients don't interfere with each other working against the same repository.  I used to get this problem with torgoisegit.  It can happen at other times as well, it's just that an interactive rebase is a fairly intensive operation, so you're more likely to hit it then.  Just close gitg and any other clients before you do your rebase.

Comment: Yeah this is terrible. I can live with lock contention meaning I need to quit a client app, but it took me awhile to realize why I was actually losing data on large rebases.